# Azure Cosmos DB Stuck in 'Creating' status

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-cosmosdb

My Azure CosmosDB account has a status of 'Creating' and I am unable to delete it.  I deployed the account from Visual Studio to my Azure subscription as I have done successfully in the past.  However, this time, it got stuck in the 'Creating' status and doesn't seem to be making any progress.

I have tried to delete the account but I get the following error message:

There is already an operation in progress which requires exlusive lock on this service mv-iot-messages. Please retry the operation after sometime.
ActivityId: 6b46b569-661e-4be5-8ccc-90d158a09047, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.5.1 (Code: PreconditionFailed)

I have attempted to delete the account from both the Azure Portal as well as from the Microsoft Azure Command prompt and I get the same message.

N/A

I expect the Cosmos DB account to fully deploy, after which, I can delete it or a way to override the 'exclusive lock'.

Comment: To solve such kind of issue,you could contact with azure cosmos db team or feedback directly,

Comment: Thanks  Jay Gong.  Since asking this question on this forum, I contacted @AzureSupport on Twitter.  They have given me a link to open a support ticket.  I was hoping that someone that frequents this forum may have already gone through this and has a quick solution.

Comment: @MaroonDev did you get an answer to your problem? I'm having a similar issue, with Terraform updating my Azure Cosmos instance.